# JavaScript form serialize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, javascriptserializer

I'm editing the HTML form tag by using a onload event which works perfectly,

```
$(function (){
window.onload=function(){
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if(x[i].getAttribute("data-reactid") == ".0"){
    x[i].id = "form1";
  }
}
}
});
```

However when I try to serialize the form onbeforeunload it is null, what am I doing wrong? I'm using chrome and I believe it doesn't work on other browsers.

```
 $(function (){
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var $k = $('#form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "MYURL",
      data: { t: Date.now(), u: document.URL, k: $k}
    });
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<form class role="form" data-reactid=".0">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1">
<button type="submit" data-reactid=".0.3">Submit</button></form>
```

Thanks!
- Digital

Comment: Can u give us a demo on jsfiddle.?

Comment: Stackoverflow has had a [perfectly good way to provide live demos in questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year. There's no need to host them on third party sites like JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `$('#form1')` doesn't match the form because it doesn't have an ID. (Possibly mitigated by the code that assigns it an ID in the first code block).

The second problem is that, even if it did, the input elements don't have names, so they can't be successful controls (and won't be included in serialised data).

The third problem is that the act of leaving the page (which triggers `onbeforeunload`) will cancel the Ajax request.

Comment: The first js code adds in a ID for the form as "form1" which works. So the form does have a ID? Right